# How may I make this run faster?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

My query is running exceedingly slow since I added the ORDER BY r.id DESC.  Without the limit it runs really slow also.  Please let me know how to make it run faster.

```
SELECT * FROM gl g, ran_to_payment r
WHERE r.refLedgerID = g.studentLedgerID
AND r.refLedgerID != 0
AND g.subAccount > 0
AND r.feeType = 1
AND g.subAccount != r.ran
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Thank you

Comment: <humor> have a T-Rex chase it!</humor>  in all honesty the !='s are going to slow things down.  is there a different way to achieve those results w/o !=?  To really help we need to know indexes/execution plans and volumne of records in each table

Comment: The point of this script was to create a method to check the database to see if there are any missing data in specific fields...such as when the ran field data is found in the gl table but not the ran_to_payment table in this example.

Comment: You may be able to avoid the join if you don't need data from the R table by using an not exists subquery.  If you need data from R then you might be able to do a coorlated subquery in the select to be faster if you only need 1-2 fields from R.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that next time.  Blessings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `*` in query. Just select the columns you need. Anyway, please try this and let me know if with this could be a litle faster.

```
SELECT * FROM gl g
INNER JOIN ran_to_payment r ON r.refLedgerID = g.studentLedgerID
AND r.refLedgerID != 0
AND g.subAccount > 0
AND r.feeType = 1
AND g.subAccount != r.ran
ORDER BY r.id DESC
```

Comment: Using `JOIN...ON` is "better" style, but does not change the performance any.

Answer (score 0):

Is the "id" column indexed? Having that indexed would speed up your query. To find out what indexes you have on that table you can run the following query.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM ran_to_payment;
```

If one doesn't already exist, you can add one by altering your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `ran_to_payment` ADD INDEX `ran_to_payment_id` (`id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(feeType, refLedgerID) -- on r
INDEX(studentLedgerID) -- on g (if it is not already the PRIMARY KEY
```